# DataTables column definitions with null values

Tags: jquery, datatables

My serialized JSON array is like this:

```js
[
    [null, null, null, null, null],
    [null, "Rough Costing", null, null, null],
    [null, null, null, null, null],
    [null, "Client", "Ua Limited", null, null],
    [null, "Product", null, null, null],
    [null, "Pro: Name", "Idam ", null, null],
    [null, "Est.: No", null, null, null],
    [null, "Time: period  ", "43299", null, null],
    [null, "Date", "15th July - 2018", null, null],
    [null, null, null, null, null]
]
```

jQuery DataTables query is like this:

```html
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Column 3</th>
            <th>Column 4</th>
            <th>Column 5</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>  
</table>
```

```js
$('#example').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": "/POPM_Trn_IOU/ExportToExcel",
        "dataSrc": ""
    },
});
```

But this only fills the DataTables rows under first column only, because there are no column definitions I guess. But the same works fine [here](http://live.datatables.net/regeveho/3/edit).

How to deal with this in my real application?

SS [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83jhr.png)

Comment: what problem you are facing? any error or anything.. describe it in your question.

Comment: it should come like online example in the link but in my real application it comes it filles vertically under first column . not like in the example.

Comment: can you add screenshot or fiddle, that you tried.

Comment: SS of the result https://i.stack.imgur.com/83jhr.png

Comment: @Raga N, it looks like you have problem with json data.

Answer (score 1):

[Reference Link Please check here For Full Running Example](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/row_details.html)

This way you can do this:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dt = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "scripts/ids-objects.php",
        "columns": [
            {
                "class":          "details-control",
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ""
            },
            { "data": "first_name" },
            { "data": "last_name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" }
        ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
    } );
```

Comment: this is not working since i dont have column names or data like { "data": "first_name" }, its just an json string. but as you can see it works fine in the online demo . but in my application it only comens under first column letter by letter for each row.

Comment: @RangaN Please Check array properly then

Comment: I did and as you can see its working fine in the online example. i can and property names to the array but i dont thing its a good way.